# Why doesn't Blend 2012 allow me to create non-Windows store projects?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, blend

I also can't view the designer. It only shows me the the XAML with existing projects.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the [Visual Studio 2012 Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx). Download [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=273878). It allows to create Silverlight and WPF applications with Blend for VS 2012.

Comment: huh, I missed that somehow.  Excellent!

Comment: @Jehof Thank you so much. I Googled the issue, but couldn't find anything.